# Common word for two people who want to meet but are not acquaintances

Tags: word-choice, idioms

I'm looking for a word to describe two people (instructor and student), who are trying to find time to met each other. Preferably one or two word expression.

Comment: When the student is ready the teacher appears.

Comment: They're trying to schedule a meeting?  They're trying to rendezvous?

Comment: Hi @Adi and welcome to ELU! Are you trying to find a noun for the type of meeting held between instructor and student? Or a word/phrase to describe the process of setting up a meeting, eg scheduling? You should be able to comment on your own questions and answers, regardless of your site reputation. Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

People who meet for the purpose of working on something together could be called *collaborators.*

Scheduling can be difficult.  These people would like to be collaborators, but they aren't yet -- so let's call them

> would-be collaborators.

Note, I made that up -- I can't think of a pre-existing word or phrase.

Here are a couple more:

> meeting seekers.
>
> meeting participants.

(Note, doodle.com uses "participants.")